# Imported CSV files from Fieldmove and QGIS only displayed as lists

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, csv

Downloaded some .csv data for an assignment I need to do (from fieldmove specifically), and am trying to display a single point for which i downloaded said data as a csv. file. However, when i try to read my dms coordinates it won't register as a point and will only load as a list. It will work with non dms coordinates for some reason (?) but those are off quite a ways (point should appear in grenoble, france, not someplace in africa).

Any suggestions?

Here's the case of it not working:

[image]

Here's the case of it working:

[image]

Comment: It depends on what options you specified during the CSV import process (using Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer). You might want to share a screenshot of the settings you used (including the preview of sample data for the working and non-working examples), in order to troubleshoot what settings you might need to use or whether the DMS coordinates are somehow malformed.